# LogstashTcpSocketAppender is not sending logs to Logstash

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I am using Docker ELK stack with my Spring Boot application. All three components are up and running at http://192.168.99.100:5601/, http://192.168.99.100:9200/ and 192.168.99.100:5000 respectively.

My logback-spring.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
<appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
    <keepAliveDuration>5 minutes</keepAliveDuration>
    <reconnectionDelay>10 second</reconnectionDelay>
    <waitStrategyType>sleeping</waitStrategyType>
    <destination>192.168.99.100:5000</destination>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <mdc/> <!-- MDC variables on the Thread will be written as JSON fields-->
            <context/> <!--Outputs entries from logback's context -->
            <logLevel/>
            <loggerName/>
            <pattern>
                    {
                    "timestamp": "%date{\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX\", UTC}",
                    "level": "%level",
                    "logger": "%logger",
                    "message": "%message",
                    "logstashMarkers": "%marker"
                    }
                </pattern>
            <threadName/>
            <message/>
            <logstashMarkers/> <!-- Useful so we can add extra information for specific log lines as Markers-->
            <arguments/> <!--or through StructuredArguments-->
           <stackTrace>
                <fieldName>stackTrace</fieldName>
                <throwableConverter class="net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter">
                    <exclude>net\.sf\.cglib\..*</exclude>
                    <maxDepthPerThrowable>30</maxDepthPerThrowable>
                    <rootCauseFirst>true</rootCauseFirst>
                </throwableConverter>
            </stackTrace>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="stash"/>
</root>
```

**The issue is that I am not able to see my logs in the Kibana and my doubt is that LogstashTcpSocketAppender is not sending logs to Logstash. Is there a way by which I can validate whether LogstashTcpSocketAppender is sending logs to Logstash or not?**

Comment: Launch logstash in the debug mode. Then run your spring boot app and check

Comment: logstash.yml-->config.debug: true. The property is set but it doesn't show any meesage

Comment: Goto /usr.share/logstash and type bin/logstash -f path/to/logstash.conf --log.level debug. Make sure you log as the sudo.

Comment: `<pattern><pattern>...</pattern></pattern>` because of reasons... (see: https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#provider_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

-check if the messages are sent to elasticsearsh : 
 192.168.99.100:9200/_search

-to check if the index was created : 
 192.168.99.100:9200/_cat/indices

-Actually if you want to see the results you should create in index in kibana (with the same name/pattern of the one created in elasticsearh):

[image]

and verify in kibana by modifying time:

[image]